# Write a function which return the digits

Tags: javascript

Given a varying number of integer arguments, return the digits that are not present in any of them.

Example:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78]  =>  "09"

[2015, 8, 26]     =>  "3479"
```

Note: the digits in the resulting string should be sorted.

Help please, how to do this with a short and simple code, which method should I use? RegEx for compare?

```
function unusedDigits(numbers) {

}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); 
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));
```

Comment: did you have a go on implementing `unusedDigits`? let us see what have you tried so far and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First concatenate the numbers into a single string:

```
> [2015, 8, 26].join('')
'2015826'
```

Then remove them from '0123456789':

```
> [...'0123456789'].filter(ch => !'2015826'.includes(ch)).join('')
'3479'
```

```js
function unusedDigits(numbers) {
  const s = numbers.join('');
  return [...'0123456789'].filter(ch => !s.includes(ch)).join('');
}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); 
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));
```

For a more efficient way if the input is huge, you can create a `Set` of digits instead of joining into a string.

Comment: For huge input, it might (though not certainly) be more efficient to loop through the input until the 'set' becomes empty.

Comment: What does mean ... here [...'0123456789']  ?

Comment: @Ector it's a short way to create the array `['0', '1', '2', ..., '9']`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax.

Comment: thanks to everybody. Now I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Set` and remove unwanted digits.

```js
function unused (array) {
    return Array
        .from([...array.join('')].reduce(
            (s, v) => (s.delete(v), s),
            new Set('0123456789')
        ))
        .join('')
}


console.log(unused([12, 34, 56, 78])); // "09"
console.log(unused([2015, 8, 26]));    // "3479"
```

An approach with short circuit

```js
function unused (array) {
    const s = new Set('0123456789');
    [...array.join('')].every(v => (s.delete(v), s.size));
    return Array
        .from(s)
        .join('')
}


console.log(unused([12, 34, 56, 78])); // "09"
console.log(unused([2015, 8, 26]));    // "3479"
```